# How to make this type of green/grey screen shader?

Tags: materials, shaders, lighting

[image][image]

Any idea on how to achieve this type of digital green/grey screen material ?

Comment: Hello, what have you tried so far and why are you not glad with it? It's just an Emission shader, no? (with a glass in front)

Comment: Hello, no I haven't made this. This is just a reference. It's in combination with the grey/black text where it gets tricky. I added another reference to indicate what I mean. Thank you @moonboots

Comment: I guess you need to duplicate your plane with an almost transparent one?

Comment: @moonboots I will try that when I get home. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a suitable black and white image for the "dot matrix screen", you can do it all in one material:

[image: Screen]